# Linguagem C - Ler arquivo binário em seu tamanho total

Tags: c, binary, fopen

Estou desenvolvendo um software que precisa ler um arquivo binário e exibir o seu conteúdo. Atualmente ele está exibindo o conteúdo corretamente, mas eu não sei como fazer o `loop` ler o **conteúdo total** do arquivo até chegar ao fim, pois atualmente eu defini um valor de **512**, mas eu desejo utilizar o `sizeof()`, para coletar o **tamanho total** de **bytes dentro do arquivo**. Como eu faço isso ?

Saída e escrita atual no terminal:

```
00 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 f0 00 f0 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a 10 0a 0a 09 09 0a 14 0e 0f 0c 10 17 14 18 18 17 14 16
```

Meu código atual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: Please insert the file name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    else
    {
        long acumulador;
        long buffer[512];
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        
        //Cannot open file
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            exit(0);
        }
        //The file was opened
        else
        {
            //Read the content
            while(!feof(file))
            {
                int i = 0;
                
                for(i = 0; i < 512; i++)
                {
                    fread(&acumulador, 1, 1, file);
                    buffer[i] = acumulador;
                    
                    printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
                    printf(" ");
                }
      
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof()` é um operador, veja na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-language/sizeof-operator-c?view=msvc-160).

O caminho comum para identificar o tamanho de um arquivo é usar `stat()` ou usar `fseek()` e `ftell()`.

#### Usando `fseek()` e `ftell()`

O trecho abaixo mostra o comum: abre o arquivo, move o cursor para o final e vê onde ele está, que é o tamanho do arquivo.

```
FILE* F = fopen(arquivo, "r");
if (F == NULL) return -1;
long posicao = ftell(F);
printf("Na abertura: \"cursor\" de \"%s\" em %ld\n",
    arquivo, posicao);
fseek(F, 0, SEEK_END);
posicao = ftell(F);
printf("Posicionado no fim: \"cursor\" em %ld\n",
    posicao);
```

#### Usando `stat()`

`stat()` preenche uma estrutura com informações sobre o arquivo, como em:

```
printf("Usando stat() para obter informacoes do arquivo:\n");
struct stat info;
if (stat(arquivo, &info) == -1)
{
    perror("Erro em lstat");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Tipo do arquivo \"%s\": ", arquivo);
printf("Tamanho: %ld bytes\n", (intmax_t)info.st_size);
printf("Última mudança de status em %s", ctime(&info.st_ctime));
printf("Último acesso em %s", ctime(&info.st_atime));
printf("Última modificação em %s", ctime(&info.st_mtime));
```

que mostra algo como:

```
Na abertura: "cursor" de "fst-0829.exe" em 0
Posicionado no fim: "cursor" em 54784
Usando stat() para obter informações do arquivo:
Tipo do arquivo "fst-0829.exe": Tamanho: 54784 bytes
Última mudança de status em Mon Aug 30 12:35:13 2021
Último acesso em Mon Aug 30 13:05:34 2021
Última modificação em Mon Aug 30 13:05:23 2021
```

No meu computador agora, em Windows:

```
struct stat
{
    _dev_t         st_dev;
    _ino_t         st_ino;
    unsigned short st_mode;
    short          st_nlink;
    short          st_uid;
    short          st_gid;
    _dev_t         st_rdev;
    _off_t         st_size;
    time_t         st_atime;
    time_t         st_mtime;
    time_t         st_ctime;
};
```

#### Um exemplo em C

Esse programa recebe o nome do arquivo na linha de comando e mostra as duas maneiras:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

int  testa_arquivo(const char*);
void uso();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt-br");
    if (argc < 2) uso();
    testa_arquivo(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

int testa_arquivo(const char* arquivo)
{
    FILE* F = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (F == NULL) return -1;
    long posicao = ftell(F);
    printf("Na abertura: \"cursor\" de \"%s\" em %ld\n",
        arquivo, posicao);
    fseek(F, 0, SEEK_END);
    posicao = ftell(F);
    printf("Posicionado no fim: \"cursor\" em %ld\n",
        posicao);
    fseek(F, 0, SEEK_SET); // volta pro inicio

    printf("Usando stat() para obter informacoes do arquivo:\n");
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(arquivo, &info) == -1)
    {
        perror("Erro em lstat");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Tipo do arquivo \"%s\": ", arquivo);
    printf("Tamanho: %ld bytes\n", (intmax_t)info.st_size);
    printf("Última mudança de status em %s", ctime(&info.st_ctime));
    printf("Último acesso em %s", ctime(&info.st_atime));
    printf("Última modificação em %s", ctime(&info.st_mtime));
    fclose(F);
    return 0;
}

void uso()
{  // o classico
    printf("Use: \"programa arquivo\"\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Saída:

```
C:> ./fst-0829 fst-0829.exe
Na abertura: "cursor" de "fst-0829.exe" em 0
Posicionado no fim: "cursor" em 54784
Usando stat() para obter informacoes do arquivo:
Tipo do arquivo "fst-0829.exe": Tamanho: 54784 bytes
Última mudança de status em Mon Aug 30 12:35:13 2021
Último acesso em Mon Aug 30 13:05:34 2021
Última modificação em Mon Aug 30 13:05:23 2021
C:>
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() não é apropriado para esta tarefa. sizeof() é uma pseudo-função que calcula o tamanho de um tipo, em tempo de compilação.

Para descobrir o tamanho do arquivo, você precisa testar o valor de retorno de fread(). No caso, como você está usando fread() para ler 1 byte de cada vez, basta testar se o retorno é <= 0. Se sim, bateu no fim.

Outra opção seria descobrir o tamanho do arquivo a priori, antes de começar a lê-lo, usando as funções fseek(), ftell() e rewind().

Comment: ok muito obrigado

Comment: sizeof() é um operador